# how to check in python if a string contains characters only form specific code page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I know that python uses solely utf8 for string encoding , but what if I need to send data to older application that is non-unicode and supports only these characters that are included in windows code-page like windows-1251 (cyrylic) etc... So here I want to detect if utf-8 string contains any character that could not by represented by given code page.

Comment: try encode and catch error if any

Comment: *python uses solely utf8 for string encoding*. No, it doesn't. Python 3 strings are unicode values. You can encode these to and from most common codecs, including Windows 1251 ('cp1251'), simply catch the exception if there are codepoints that cannot be encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is lib for encoding detection: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet (*Character encoding auto-detection in Python. As smart as your browser. Open source*)

Detects...

- ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16 (2 variants), UTF-32 (4 variants)
- Big5, GB2312, EUC-TW, HZ-GB-2312, ISO-2022-CN (Traditional and Simplified Chinese)
- EUC-JP, SHIFT_JIS, ISO-2022-JP (Japanese)
- EUC-KR, ISO-2022-KR (Korean)
- KOI8-R, MacCyrillic, IBM855, IBM866, ISO-8859-5, windows-1251 (Cyrillic)
- ISO-8859-2, windows-1250 (Hungarian)
- ISO-8859-5, windows-1251 (Bulgarian)
- windows-1252 (English)
- ISO-8859-7, windows-1253 (Greek)
- ISO-8859-8, windows-1255 (Visual and Logical Hebrew)
- TIS-620 (Thai)

example from docs:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> rawdata = urllib.urlopen('http://yahoo.co.jp/').read()
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(rawdata)
{'encoding': 'EUC-JP', 'confidence': 0.99}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where `blah` is your string and `ascii` is your encoding:

```
blah = u'\uffff'
try:
    blah.encode('ascii')
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    # nope - can't do it...
```

Comment: @alko: Python 3.3 supports `u''` prefixes for ease of porting between 2 and 3. It is redundant here, though.

Comment: It's a mix... depending if the Python 3.x version being used is one that has the `u` prefix removed or not :)